# What is the Destiny Cloud Fist build?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

What is the Destiny Cloud Fist build?  I've heard SC2 players talking about it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

H to the Usky Husky came up with it when casting a game.  It describes the standard terran 1/1/1 build which is 1 barracks, 1 factory and 1 starport.

Comment: He made up the name because, according to him, he would say "one" too many times trying to say "one one one", so this made it easier.

Comment: I think it was first used in one of the Idra vs Silver games.

Comment: @Robb H to the Usky?

Comment: It is intended as a joke.  it does not have any specific meaning as far as I know.  I imagine that he just made up some words on the spot, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @tzenes if you watch husky's casts, he often introduces himself as "h to the usky husky"

Comment: @Peter I know, but did he have to repeat it? I don't particularly like Husky as a caster, but I try and put up with the fact that people do.  However, when all of a sudden he has to be "gangsta" then the hackles on the back of my neck bristle.

Comment: @tzenes I can see how husky wouldn't be everyone's cup of tea. that said, I am pretty sure he is not seriously trying to be gangsta. I don't think a gangsta would ruin their tough guy image with video of themselves puking after skydiving :)   IMO, he just likes being silly, like with "destiny cloudfist"

Comment: @Peter H to the Usky is a reference to JayZ.  I don't want to get into a discussion over whether or not he's trying to be gangsta and why I dislike it, the bottom line is I don't.

Comment: In [this replay](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0Ak9h_I9lU) he explains his reasons again.

Comment: The reason this build is so appealing is because of the extreme flexibility you have once completed. You can react and counter quickly.

Answer (score 27):

That's right, it's Barracks/Factory/Starport. Just wanted to add an illustration which someone did a few days ago of this:

[image]

That's from http://starcraft.org/art/sketches/811

Comment: Awesome as that is, I cannot in good conscience upvote it without it being community wiki.

Answer (score -1):

According to the "Bureau of Un-Newbing the Newbs", all "Destiny Cloud Fist" really means is that it is the fastest way to get flying units to attack your enemy.